# Swift 3 - Activity Indicator delay or not responding

Tags: json, autolayout, swift3, delay

I have field and button when you fill the field with content and click the button:

```
@IBAction func dpSomething(_ sender: UIButton) {
    activityIndicator.startAnimating()
    activityIndicator.isHidden = false
    field.isHidden = true
    send.isHidden = true
    let url = "http://urlwithjson"
    let session = URLSession.shared
    DispatchQueue.main.async { [unowned self] in
        let task = session.dataTask(with: URL(string: url)!) { (data, response, error) in
            if(error==nil){
                        do {
                            let jsonData = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: .mutableContainers) as! NSDictionary
                                if((jsonData["response"] as! Int) == 0){
                                    self.responseL.text = "no results"
                                }
                            self.activityIndicator.stopAnimating()
                            self.responseL.isHidden = false
                        } catch _ {}
            }
        }
        task.resume()
    }

}
```

when I use print it prints me almost immediately the JSON, but activity indicator needs 10-20 secs to disappear or sometimes it doesn't disappear. Can somebody tells me why? And also when I change the text in the label I receive error in console:

> This application is modifying the autolayout engine from a background thread, which can lead to engine corruption and weird crashes. This will cause an exception in a future release.

Why this is happening ?

Comment: seems your running network request on main thread which is not encouraged

Comment: instead try `DispatchQueue.main.async {
        self.activityIndicator.stopAnimating()
        self.responseL.isHidden = false
    }`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all Add the following code after                     `activityIndicator.startAnimating()` , this code will hide the activity indicator ones you call `self.activityIndicator.stopAnimating()`:

```
activityIndicator.hidesWhenStopped = true
```

Also you are only hiding the activity indicator if the response succeeded, so you may need to hide the indicator when there is an error in catch block and in else block when you get an error from api response

Another point is when you make your request it's not supposed to be in main thread, only in background and then when you need to update the UI then do use main thread , so finally here is the full code you may need:

```
 @IBAction func dpSomething(_ sender: UIButton) {
    activityIndicator.startAnimating()
    activityIndicator.isHidden = false
    activityIndicator.hidesWhenStopped = true
    field.isHidden = true
    send.isHidden = true
    let url = "http://urlwithjson"
    let session = URLSession.shared
    let task = session.dataTask(with: URL(string: url)!) { (data, response, error) in
            if(error==nil){
                do {
                    let jsonData = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: .mutableContainers) as! NSDictionary
                    if((jsonData["response"] as! Int) == 0){
                        DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        //Update your UI here


                         self.responseL.text = "no results"
                        }
               }

                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        //Update your UI here
                        self.activityIndicator.stopAnimating()
                        self.responseL.isHidden = false
                    }

                } catch _ {

                    // JSONSerialization error might happen so hide the indicator
                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        //Update your UI here
                        self.activityIndicator.stopAnimating()
                        self.responseL.isHidden = false
                    }

                }
            }else {
                // api response error might happen so hide the indicator
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    //Update your UI here
                    self.activityIndicator.stopAnimating()
                    self.responseL.isHidden = false
                }

            }
        }
        task.resume()

}
```

Comment: now its working immediately, but the response label is changing after 10 seconds :D, and I still receive : This application is modifying the autolayout engine from a background thread after the engine was accessed from the main thread. This can lead to engine corruption and weird crashes.

Comment: @BogdanBogdanov I have edited my answer , the label must be also updated from main thread ! Let me know if it work

Answer (score 2):

You need to only make `UI` changes on `main` thread never call Async API call on main thread.

```
    let task = session.dataTask(with: URL(string: url)!) { (data, response, error) in
        if(error==nil){
                    do {
                        let jsonData = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: .mutableContainers) as! NSDictionary
                            if((jsonData["response"] as! Int) == 0){
                                self.responseL.text = "no results"
                            }
                        DispatchQueue.main.async {
                            self.activityIndicator.stopAnimating()
                            self.activityIndicator.isHidden = true
                            self.responseL.isHidden = false
                        }
                    } catch _ {}
        }
    }
    task.resume()
```

Comment: @Ashok Thanks mate :)